# On scroll: move up content div

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I am creating a website using jquery parallax. I have three divs corresponds to three different pages respectively. I have still background (on scrolling pages background remains still). I have logo image in first page given position fixed. So on scroll logo remains there. That is ok for second page. For third page, i need the logo to move up along with the div.How can i do that? Is there any function for that in jquery parallax

Background css:

```
 body{
   background:url(images/new.jpeg);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size:100% 100%;
   background-attachment:fixed;
 }
```

Logo:

```
<div class="logocenter">
    <img src="images/stampedlogo.png" style="width: 200px;height: 200px;position: fixed;" alt="logo"/>
</div>
```

Please see [my site](http://applicate.co.nz/stampede/index.html)

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: always post your code with the question ..or create a fiddle rather than posting a link... the link might not work in near future or you might change the location of your file in that case the link won't  work.. which infact, is not helpful for user looking for answer similar to your question in near future

Comment: Also just as a side note, your CSS has this in it: `background-color:rgbargba(255,255,255,0.7);`, you only need one `rgba`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use code below:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {   
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 500) {
       $('.logocenter').fadeOut();
   }
});
```